# iOS - UIButton as Subview on UIAlertController not firing events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uialertcontroller

I am adding UIButton on UIAlertController but it is not firing the method on any events.

```
UIButton *cancelBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[cancelBtn setFrame:CGRectMake((_alertController.view.frame.size.width/2)-30, _alertController.view.frame.size.height-50, 60, 30)];
[cancelBtn setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[cancelBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(forceFullDismiss_FireDelegate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cancelBtn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

[_alertController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[_alertController.view addSubview:cancelBtn];
```

The button seems to be highlighted but the respective events are not firing.

What is the issue here?

Comment: and there is no error about a target? breakpoint just does not stop in `forceFullDismiss_FireDelegate` ?

Comment: No Errors. Yes the breakpoint doesn't stops at forceFullDismiss_FireDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from `UIAlertController` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller).

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

If you want to add a cancel button, you can use

```
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    //  action on cancel
}];

[_alertController addAction:cancel];
```